# AJAX not POSTing any data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post

I have some code i've been working on to have a box disappear once you click a button without refreshing the whole page, I can't get over my current hurdle. My AJAX doesn't seem to be posting any data, as you can see from the code below, I have a confirmation pop up which works and does pop up and when you click ok it SHOULD POST the ID to another page where the SQL runs, but it doesn't and i've tried testing it with echoing the POST to see if it retrieves it and no luck.

Any ideas why it won't post the data?

P.s I've checked to make sure the function is correct but here it is so you can see what the user clicks, and the id is 100% there

```
 <button onclick='good(<?= $appRow['customer_appointments_id']; ?>)' class='w3-button w3-block w3-green w3-section'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></button>
```

**AJAX**

```
      function good(id){
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to complete this appointment?")) {
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "scripts/lead/completeLeadTask.php",
             data: ({
                 id: id
             }),
             cache: false,
             success: function(html) {
                $(".delete_mem" + id).fadeOut('slow');
             }
         });
```

**Scripts/lead/completeLeadTask.php**

```
    echo $_POST['id'];

  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `customer_appointments` SET `customer_appointments_status` = 'c' WHERE `customer_appointments`.`customer_appointments_id` = ?")->execute([$_POST['id']]);
  $stmt = null;
```

Comment: can you get the id on button click????

Comment: How would I test that?

Comment: function good(id){ `alert(id);`

Comment: Yes, that works. I get the correct id

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `id` to the completeLeadTask.php page but using `$_POST['customer_appointment_id']` when updating the database.

I removed the parenthesis from the data in the ajax request.

```
function good(id){
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to complete this appointment?")) {
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "scripts/lead/completeLeadTask.php",
             data: {
                 id: id
             },
             cache: false,
             success: function(html) {
                $(".delete_mem" + id).fadeOut('slow');
             }
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: I will update my question, but as you can see above the SQL I tried doing echo id and that won't print anything either

Comment: Updated, does that work? I believe the parenthesis in the "data" might have caused an issue.

Comment: I've just tried replacing my code for yours and I don't get anything now, not even the confirm box so i've put it back to my old code

Comment: Well then use your code, but remove the ( ) in `data: ({ id: id })`. That's all I did, so any errors are from copying/pasting without looking.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, I appreciate the help but it didn't change anything, I still get the confirmation box but after I click 'Ok' nothing happens

Comment: if you get echo $_POST['id']; correctly then problem is in update query.

Comment: I just tested this locally and it works. The issue is probably with your query.